# I have bind numbers to CombBox. I want change value comboBox and textBox changed value

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-8, combobox, textbox

I want change number from `ComboBox` and change value in `TextBox`.

(For example I have number =2 and content at "lblblblb" ofc. this is in `ObservableCollection<string>`, so I to call `ContentWithListView[SelectNumberStep]`)

**ReadPage.xaml**

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="580,154,0,0" 
 TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ContentWithListView[SelectNumberStep],Mode=TwoWay}"
 VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="725" Height="82"/>

<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="440,154,0,0" 
 ItemsSource="{Binding NumberStep,Mode=TwoWay}" 
 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectNumberStep,Mode=TwoWay}" 
 VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="95" Height="77" />
```

How I change content in TextBox from CombBox numbers?

**ReadViewModel.cs**

```
private ObservableCollection<string> contentWithListView;
public ObservableCollection<string> ContentWithListView
{
    get
    {
        return this.contentWithListView;
    }

    set
    {
        this.contentWithListView = value;
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<int> stepNumber;
public ObservableCollection<int> NumberStep
{
    get
    {
        return this.stepNumber;
    }

    set
    {
        this.stepNumber = value;
    }
}

private int selectNumberStep;
public int SelectNumberStep
{
    get
    {
        return this.selectNumberStep;
    }

    set
    {
        this.selectNumberStep = value;    
    }
}
```

Comment: What is you question?

Comment: How I change content in TextBox from CombBox numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

previous answer doesn't integrate the fact he textbox content have to be in TwoWays so, in such scenario, you could consolidate your properties with the INotifyPropertyChanged interface like that:

***Xaml part***

```
<StackPanel d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=classes:StackOverFlowX }">

    <TextBox Text="{Binding Content, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding NumberStep, Mode=TwoWay}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectNumberStep,Mode=TwoWay}"/>

</StackPanel>
```

***Class***

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public class StackOverFlowX : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public StackOverFlowX()
    {

    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> contentWithListView;
    public ObservableCollection<string> ContentWithListView
    {
        get
        {
            return this.contentWithListView;
        }

        set
        {
            this.contentWithListView = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<int> stepNumber;
    public ObservableCollection<int> NumberStep
    {
        get
        {
            return this.stepNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            this.stepNumber = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private int selectNumberStep;
    public int SelectNumberStep
    {
        get
        {
            return this.selectNumberStep;
        }
        set
        {
            this.selectNumberStep = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged("Content");
        }
    }

    private string _content;
    public string Content
    {
        get
        {
            return contentWithListView[this.SelectNumberStep];
        }
        set
        {
            this._content = value;

            if (contentWithListView.IndexOf(value) > -1)
            {
                SelectNumberStep = contentWithListView.IndexOf(value);
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectNumberStep");
            }

            OnPropertyChanged();

        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var eventHandler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (eventHandler != null)
        {
            eventHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change your view model code around, so that the text box binds to a scalar string value which is updated on the `SelectNumberStep` change:

```
public string Content
{
   get
   { 
      // bounds checking here..
      return contentWithListView[this.SelectNumberStep];
   }
}

public int SelectNumberStep
{
    get
    {
        return this.selectNumberStep;
    }

    set
    {
        this.selectNumberStep = value;
        this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.SelectNumberStep);
        this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.Content);
    }
}

<TextBox Text="{Binding Content}" ... />
```